# android base64 cli conversion utilities

Tags: macos, bash, base64

I want to encode a file into android base64. Android's sdk has a utility method that does this. I should be able to avoid doing any Android programming to solve this. There are utilities for windows that can do this as well.

For my Mac, I've tried using the base64 shell command from fourmilab.ch

It is not giving me usable results, and it inserts spaces and newlines. Also the output files seem to have far too few characters.

Also, the library method in the Android sdk and the windows utility have an optional offset for the base64 which it would be nice to be able to use.